# A shocker in soccer

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

> I'm a shocker in soccer;
>   An attack with many racks;
>   I sell while you yell,
>   And let rage be gone when switched on.

What am I? But there's a twist - *I sort of lied to you, if you can figure out how.*

**Hint 1:**

> This is pretty clearly gibberish as is. But have you ever seen where you can switch what kind of shirt/face/body type goes on a certain character? I haven't been entirely truthful as to which dependent/independent clauses line up with which...

**Hint 2:**

> I realize the last hint spawns all sorts of hellish combinations. Prune what you may, then realize I'm not *that* big of a liar. I was systematic in mis-attaching each clause.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are

> An outlet

Because you have to

> Change the order of the phrases by moving them up by one:

That is

> I'm a shocker when switched on; 
>  **an electrical outlet** 
>  An attack in soccer; 
>  **an outlet pass** 
>  I sell with many racks, 
>  **an outlet mall or store** 
>  And let rage be gone while you yell. 
>  **an outlet for your anger**