# A shocker in soccer, pt. 2

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

> You’ll spar better with five letters;
>   I charge a fee, must be me;
>   A precise gun if I’m done;
>   And I’m a band to cross land.

What am I?

*Note: This riddle takes the form of [A shocker in soccer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/94099/a-shocker-in-soccer). The key is to take a gibberish riddle and figure out which second half of the line matches up with the first half before solving for the word or phrase. Note that I was not systematic with mismatching lines this time.*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Perhaps you are

> a **train**?

I believe the actual riddle goes something like this:

> You’ll spar better if I’m done;
>  I charge a fee to cross land;
>  A precise gun must be me;
>  And I’m a band with five letters.

Line 1:

> When you're done *training*, you'll be a better fighter.

Line 2:

> You need to pay for a ticket in order to ride on a train to take you across the land.

Line 3:

> A precise gun must be *trained* on its target.

Line 4:

> [Train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Train_(band)) is the name of a rock band and has five letters.